# How can I center an image link in html?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use an image as a link but only one image can be clicked and the other images aren't working as links. I use text-center class
my HTML code:

```
 <div class="foot text-center">
            <a  href="https://www.facebook.com/basmaEsmailGh/"><img src="img/face.png" alt="facebook"></a>
             <a href="https://twitter.com"> <img src="img/tw.png" alt="twitter"></a>
           <a href="https://www.linkedin.com"> <img src="img/in.png" alt="linkedin"> </a>
       </div>
```

and my css file only has for "foot" class:

```
.foot{
height: 100px;
background-color: #401BE6;
```

}

what is the problem?

Comment: The code in your question doesn't reproduce the problem in the body of the post. It might be reproducing the issue in the title depending on what you mean by "centered". The answers below are making different assumptions about the what you want; can you edit your question so 1) the code reproduces the issue with the links and 2) clarify what you mean by centered (links on separate lines, on the same line spaced out, something else).

Answer (score 0):

u need to define a `display: block;` on that `<a href=''>` element

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements can't be aligned center unless we use the `display: block` property on them so apply the `display: block` property to the anchor elements

Answer (score 0):

I hope I interpreted your desired final outcome.
https://jsfiddle.net/vLk8gtjs/30/

Make your buttons inline instead of vertically stacked.
Therefore: create a new class and class each link. I changed the bg to make it easier for me to work with

```
.img_links {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
}
```

This aligns links within your div footer box.

I'm not sure why your links aren't working.  Try this solution out and leave a comment if your images are displayed, but not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

OPTION ONE

```
.foot.text-center {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

OPTION TWO (INLINE CSS)

```
<div class="foot text-center" align="center">
    <a  href="https://www.facebook.com/basmaEsmailGh/"><img src="img/face.png" alt="facebook"></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com"> <img src="img/tw.png" alt="twitter"></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com"> <img src="img/in.png" alt="linkedin"> </a>
</div>
```